# Viewing thousands of PDF files very rapidly

Tags: pdf, filemanager

I have many thousands of PDF files in a directory, and I need to quickly view them one-by-one.

I want to be able to open one, look at it, and then quickly (like with a single keypress) move on to the next PDF file.

Geeqie supports this workflow perfectly for images, but it does not appear to support displaying PDF files at this time.

Is there another file manager, PDF viewer or image viewer that behaves just like Geeqie, but that can display PDF files?

I have tried file managers like Thunar, Konqueror, and Dolphin, but they do not offer large enough previews or thumbnails. I have also tried numerous PDF viewers, but they did not support opening multiple PDF files or quickly moving to a new file.

Can anyone suggest any software for Ubuntu that would meet my needs?

Answer (score 2):

Assume the files are in the folder `~/myfiles`. You can run this loop in a terminal (copy-paste):

```shell
for pdffile in ~/myfiles/*.pdf ;  do evince "$pdffile" ;  done
```

To jump to the next file just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in the Evince window (to close it and open the next file).

FWIW, I am not sure how useful this would be considering that you need to view "thousands" of files...