# View thousands of pdf files one after another from a list

Tags: command-line, bash, previews

I have taken up a task of manually generating Library essential data from huge pdf library; what I want is: use a script with file names, to open a pdf file instance, review it and after I close current instance subsequent pdf instance is started. Is this possible.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430141/viewing-thousands-of-pdf-files-very-rapidly) doesnt talk about using filenames list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a file with a filename per line, you could use this command:

```
while read file; do xdg-open "$file"; done < files.txt
```

You can replace `xdg-open` by the program of your choice, such as `evince` or `okular`.

If the PDF files are mainly text, you can also consider using the `pdftotext` command to convert PDF files to text files. In that way, you can use any text editor to review the contents. `gedit` and `kate` support tabs for example. Example:

```
while read file; do pdftotext "$file"; done < files.txt
```

This converts a PDF file such as `foo.pdf` to a text file, `foo.txt`.

For more details on the command invocation of `pdftotext`, see its manual page [`pdftotext(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pdftotext.1).

Comment: I am working non-ocr-able old scans. so pdftotext is not going to help me. I used `ls -1` to make list of files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try I, Librarian. It is not a command line, but it could help to make your task more bearable.

http://i-librarian.net